# How to use SphinxSE table + sort by "weight desc" when there are other joins in query?

Tags: join, sphinx, mariadb

By default, when you perform query to sphinx table, Sphinx engine returns rows which are already sorted by query weight and does it really fast.

So, when I do this:

```
select
 article.name
from article
 left join article_ft on article._id=article_ft.id
where article_ft.query='some text;mode=any;';
```

Where:

- `article` is InnoDB like table.
- `article_ft` is Sphinx table.

Both of them (`article.name` and `article_ft`) contain these data (1 line = 1 row):

```
This is text.
This is also some text.
This is another text.
```

Sphinx engine will return rows like:

```
This is also some text.
This is text.
This is another text.
```

But, If I do something like this:

```
select
 article.name
from article
 left join article_ft on article._id=article_ft.id
 left join article_category on article.category=article_category._id
where article_ft.query='some text;mode=any;';
```

It seems, MariaDB sorts it by its own way here.

Even If I provide Sphinx's 'sort' option like this:

```
select
 article.name
from article
 left join article_ft on article._id=article_ft.id
 left join article_category on article.category=article_category._id
where article_ft.query='some text;mode=any;sort=extended:@weight desc;';
```

Still it doesn't work.

Changing order of `join`s doesn't work as well.

If I use `order by article_ft.weight DESC` MariaDB returns error message like:

```
Error: ER_ILLEGAL_HA: Storage engine SPHINX of the table `article_ft` doesn't have this option
```

in case if `article` has no rows that could match condition like `article.category=50`.

`article_ft` was created using this:

```
CREATE TABLE article_ft
(
    id        BIGINT NOT NULL,
    weight      INTEGER NOT NULL,
    query       VARCHAR(3072) NOT NULL,
    INDEX(query)
) ENGINE=SPHINX CONNECTION="sphinx://192.168.1.98:9402/article_ft";
```

How to use this "magical" `sort by weight` feature if query contains more joins with no errors in return?

Thanks forward, for any reply!

P.S. Can't provide you a fiddle for this because I do not know any SQL fiddle online service which supports Sphinx Tables. Also if you found more relevant topic question I'll appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

Put the `article_ft` table first in the query. ie `... article_ft inner join article ...`

---

Or maybe use `FORCE INDEX`, to force the use of the `query` index. Then it might honour the sort order.

---

Failing that use a subquery?

```
(select name,weight from article_ft ... ) order by weight desc;
```

Comment: 1: This works but I need to reconstruct a pipeline of my app.
2: Can you provide a little example query on how to use 'FORCE INDEX' with given tables (article, article_ft)? Because whatever I try with 'FORCE INDEX' it gives errors like "ERROR 1176 (42000): Key 'id' doesn't exist in table 'article_ft'"
3: Same as 1.
Thanks!